# An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline mode

Tags: iis-7, .net

I have a plesk 10.2 shared hosting running IIS 7. Trying to run .Net 4.0 website. It gives following error :

```
HTTP Error 500.23 - Internal Server Error
An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in 
Integrated managed pipeline mode.
```

Found this link

http://forum.parallels.com/pda/index.php/t-95091.html

But could not found Handler Mappings section in control panel.

Any solution??

Answer (score 4):

You can find the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209999/an-asp-net-setting-has-been-detected-that-does-not-apply-in-integrated-managed-p

Which is: Make sure to add this to your web.config

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This also happened to us migrating from Parallels Plesk legacy to Parallels Plesk PPA and adding this setting sorted it out.